# How to enable multi touch in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Could anyone show me how to enable multi touch in cocos2d application please? I am new to this. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Either he means Cocoa or maybe http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use setMultipleTouchEnabled:Yes for your UIWindow or UIView, and then set the isTouchEnabled property for the layer on which you want to receive touches.

Comment: Since whatever version of cocos2d do it for EAGLView: [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 18):

I tested on Cocos2D 1.0rc2, and in that version you must put the setMultipleTouchEnabled command in the OpenGL view (in the appdelegate class):

```
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

and in your CCLayer init function:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```