# Button not clickable when moving the sneakyjoystick — Cocos2D Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented the sneakyness/sneakyinput files in my game and I have made a joystick. I have also added a button, a `CCMenuItem`:

```
- (void)initJoystick {
SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init];

joystickBase.backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"base.png"];
joystickBase.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"joystick.png"];
joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)];

joystickBase.position = ccp(90, 90);

[self addChild:joystickBase z:1000];

leftJoystick = [joystickBase.joystick retain];


CCLabelTTF *shootLabel = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"Shoot" fontName:@"helvetica" fontSize:32.0];
CCMenuItem *shootItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:shootLabel target:self selector:@selector(shootTapped)];
shootItem.color = ccORANGE;
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:shootItem, nil];
menu.position = ccp(500, 25);
[self addChild:menu z:1000];
}
```

The joystick works fine but while I'm moving it the button doesn't recognize any presses. When I have `CCMenuItems` instead of a joystick the other button works fine but not with the joystick. So is anyone familiar with the sneakiness files or do anyone know how I can make both clickable at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not enabled multitouch for the view/window.[1]

something along the lines of this:

```
[view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

also, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774465/how-to-enable-multi-touch-in-cocos2d)

[1] https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/tests/TouchesTest/TouchesDemoAppDelegate.m#L19