# Enable Multi-touch in Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

There are many buttons in my game but some functions require pressing 2 buttons at once. Now when I try to press 2 buttons at once it only detects one. What could I do to detect both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable multi touch in cocos2d?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774465/how-to-enable-multi-touch-in-cocos2d)

Comment: It answers the question for  Cocos2D 1.0rc2 not 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable multi-touch in the new Cocos2d 3.0

In your `- (id)init`. This now Enables multi-touch to the whole scene.

first add

```
self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Right under the

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

To finish it off add

```
jButton.exclusiveTouch = NO;
jButton.claimsUserInteraction = NO;
```

to your buttons. Im sorry i cannot explain how this works (i hope somebody can explain) but it works!